# Is it possible to use build or release metadata as a configuration parameter in a release template?

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management

Is it possible to use (TFS) build, or (InRelease/Release Management) release metadata - especially e.g. release name, or changeset number - as the value of a configuration variable for an activity in InRelease/TFS Release Management?

For example, is it possible to provide a path in my TFS build metadata, and have that path used as the "FilePath" argument for the "Run Command Line" action?

Is it possible to provide a "FilePath" argument along the lines of `\server\[ReleaseName]\Foo` to the "Run Command Line" action?

Is there a more in-depth reference than the user guide that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some limited TFS information you can use in Release Management. This is only available for Components (not for Actions).

Some more articles are available from the old InRelease support site (which will be moved in the near future). This specific [article](http://incyclesoftware.zendesk.com/entries/24422737) is related to the metadata available and how to use it.